# Downloading an image from Cloud Firestore directly into an imageView using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm completely new to Firebase and i just went through the setup and the documentation regarding the real-time database and the cloud firestore. I'm trying to test the part of the docs where you can Download Images with FirebaseUI directly into an ImageView ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0)). This is their code:

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);FirebaseUIActivity.java
```

And this is my code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference iconRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/rest_of_the_link");

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .load(iconRef)
        .into(imageView);
```

}

I have a .webp image in firestore and i made a reference to it using `StorageReference iconRef` and then tried loading that into the ImageView. Sadly, that didn't work. What am i missing here? Also, was the `GlideApp` part replaced with `Glide` because i can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a file called GlideApp (or whatever you want) as :

`@GlideModule
class GlideApp extends AppGlideModule {
}`

and then using `GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(iconRef)
        .into(imageView);`